# Volatile and non-volatile solutes in solution

Tags: solutions, vapor-pressure

What is the difference between having a volatile versus a non-volatile solute at the boiling point of the solution?

I have been getting mixed answers online concerning the differences outlined above. This is what I have gathered so far:

> A non-volatile solute does not produce vapour at the boiling point of the solution.
>
> A volatile solute does produce vapour at the boiling point of the solution.

Can someone confirm these definitions?

Comment: Nonvolatile solutes have negligible vapor pressures when doing problems in chem texts.  Volatile solutes must be accounted for.

Answer (score 2):

A substance with higher vapour pressure vaporizes more readily than a substance with a lower vapour pressure. In case of a volatile solute this has a high vapour pressure and hence produces vapour. While in the case of a non-volatile solute due to its lower vapour pressure it does not produce vapour. The vapor pressure of a substance is the pressure at which its gas phase is in equilibrium with its condensed phases (liquid or solid).